# 'AsyncIOMotorLatentCommandCursor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mongodb, sanic, motorengine

I am working with motorclient and i have the following query where i want get the average rating of an certain user.

```
res = apps.db.rating.aggregate({
        "$group": {
            "_id": ObjectId(user_id),
            "avg_rating": {"$avg": "$rating"}
        }
    })
```

then while i am trying to extract that average value like
       `print('avg rating', res['avg_rating'])`

this raise an error `TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorLatentCommandCursor' object is not subscriptable`

I have googled a lot already but i didn't found solution of how i can extract a resutl from an aggregate query using `motor`.

Answer (score 0):

You should await cursor or iterate through [aggregate](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_motor_collection.html#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorCollection.aggregate). In addition, make changes for pipeline: it should be a list.